# Geometric Progression with complex common ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does it make sense to have an complex number for general Geometric Progression?

For example,

$a, ak, ak^2,\ldots$

$k$ being complex number with real and imaginary part.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, and all the usual rules still apply; for example the series

$\displaystyle \sum_0^n k^i = \dfrac{k^{n + 1} - 1}{k - 1}, \tag 1$

and if

$\vert k \vert < 1, \tag 2$

$\displaystyle \sum_0^\infty k^i = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{k^{n + 1} - 1}{k - 1} = \dfrac{-1}{k - 1} = \dfrac{1}{1 - k}, \tag 2$

and so forth.  These things in fact enter into more advanced results in complex analysis etc.